# Convergence bounds for ergodic random walk

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walks

We are given a simple connected graph $G(V,E)$, where $V$ and $E$ denote the vertex and edge sets respectively. Let $G'(V,E')$ be the graph generated by $G$ by adding one self-loop edge for each vertex in $V$. We denote by $A$ and $A'$, and $D$ and $D'$ the two adjacency matrix and the two diagonal matrix containing the vertex degrees of $G$ and $G'$ respectively.  Let's consider the random walk transition matrix $P:=D^{-1}A'$.

---

**Question:** How small must necessarily be $t$ in terms of the topological/spectral graph properties of $G$ or $G'$, to have $\|\mathbf{v}P^{t}-\mathbf{\pi}\|_2$ bounded away from $0$ when $n\to\infty$?